# SSH: Connect to Host XXXXX Port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, sftp

Estou enfrentando um problema no meu *Ubuntu* e também no *Windows* em que eu não consigo acessar nenhum `SSH` e `SFTP`. Somente recebo a mensagem de:  "`Connection Timed Out`". Já enviei o `IP` para meus amigos, e todos eles conseguiram acessá-lo sem problemas, somente eu que estou com este problema.

Mensagem informada na hora do erro:

```
SSH: connect to host xxxxx port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: A porta 22 do cliente deve está sendo utilizada por outro serviço

Comment: Dá uma olhada na sua infraestrutura: roteador, firewall etc... vê se a segurança não está pegando a porta 22. Aliás, você está conseguindo se conectar em outras máquinas por SSH?

Comment: Não consigo conectar a nenhum ssh amigo. 
como posso ver se a porta 22 esta sendo usada?

Comment: Esse erro acontece com qualquer ssh feito de sua conexão???
Verifique se seu roteador tem o recurso de virtual servers, se tiver coloque o ip do destino e a porta, no caso a 22 e tente acessar.

Comment: Sim amigo, nenhum ssh conecta.
Seria isso? : http://prntscr.com/f2erew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera eu consegui resolver. o problema é que meu roteador estava bloqueando as portas menore que 1200. não sei por qual motivo... eu troquei a porta do ssh para > 1200 e funcionou. no meu caso eu coloquei 1500.

Quem estiver com esse problema ai está a solução, E obrigado a quem tentou ajudar.

Comment: Eu havia recentemente aumentado a velocidade da minha internet, e o Modem foi trocado por outro mais potente. Após isso, não consegui mais usar o ssh. Entrei nas configurações e não vi nenhuma restrição nas portas, vou ter que ligar para NET, acredito que seja um bloqueio direto deles.